# Finding contents of failed email sent from VBSCRIPT on Windows Server 2008

Tags: vbscript, windows-server-2008-r2

I made a dumb mistake and am hoping someone is smart enough to help me out of it :)

Using CDOSYS to send email from VBSCRIPT on an old web site. Switched servers; new host requires using a specific IP address for outgoing mail server. My previous host required simply "localhost" I failed to change that for a particular page. Analytics show me the form was submitted and, you guessed it, I would really like to have the contents of that failed email.

It never registered within SmarterMail, so it isn't in the logs there... Could at least part of the info be stored away in a log file somewhere? I was able to access the site logs and determine the IP address of the user that completed the form if that helps.

Thanks for taking the time and for any ideas!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible it's in the local SMTP server's "badmail" folder. If it's not there, you're out of luck.